# Rememberable Numbers for a Domain Name

Tags: domains

Is there a list of significant numbers that people link meaning to?

For example saying **365** many people link to days in a year, and **24 7** links to **24/7** (if pronounced correctly)

Basically little tricks like these help newcomers (hopefully) to remember brands/domain names better.

Comment: If you cannot think of this numbers offhanded, then they are probably not numbers people will recognize easily, are they?

Comment: @martinstoeckl good point.  Its is just sometimes difficult to remember things so common.  Its easy until I actually try to remember frequent #s. Another example of common numbers `98.6`, which most Westerners instantly link to body temp.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to define "people" before trying to do this.
Like trying to invoke [color meanings](http://www.informationisbeautiful.net/visualizations/colours-in-cultures/), this requires research to make sure you're actually saying what you think, and don't play off some other meaning you didn't plan. Or at least try not to, as it's pretty much going to be impossible without an intentionally limited audience. Just about any number is going to have some significance, depending what direction you come at this from. There are some generic(-ish) cultural ones like you list–which culture?–but then you also have further complications like:

- [Numbers in Chinese culture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numbers_in_Chinese_culture), and the [Chinese calendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_calendar) given your examples
- [Significance of numbers in Judaism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significance_of_numbers_in_Judaism)
- [All sorts of numerology systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerology)

And so on.

Comment: hm... I guess when I say people I'm referencing the Western Culture mainly